# Linking Index To PHP Page

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to link the index page of a site to a PHP page. The PHP is a contact page with a form. Which was working 100% before I turned into a PHP file.  As of right now, I'm getting an "HTTP ERROR 500", message.

Index.html code that links to the php page.

```
  <a href="quote.php" target="blank" class="ghost-btn">Get A Quote</a>
```

PHP code I'm using on the second page (Quote.PHP).

```
<?php
        include 'mailer.php';
        if($_Get['success']) == 1 {
          echo "<div class=\"form-messages success\"> Thank you! Your message has been sent. </div>";
        }

        if ($_Get['success']) == -1 {
          echo "<div class=\"form-messages error\"> Oops! Something went wrong please try again. </div>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: What type of value you store in $_GET['success'] ????

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error, change  `if($_Get['success']) == 1`  to  `if($_GET['success'] == 1)`

Comment: When getting a 500 check your error logs. You have multiple issues here.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the file name to lowercase so it matches the link.

```
quote.php
```

Also a different error might arise, I believe the $_Get array should also be

```
$_GET
```

Not sure what error detection you have in your mailer.php file but there should probably also be something like

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])){ \\do stuff }
```

Your link is not passing a variable **success** thus this is likely not going to function correctly

```
<a href="quote.php?success=1" target="blank" class="ghost-btn">Get A Quote</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value with url

```
<a href="quote.php?success=1" target="blank" class="ghost-btn">Get A Quote</a>
```

Your `$_get['sucess']` should change to `$_GET['success']`
And `if($_Get['success']) == 1` should change to `if($_GET['success'] == 1 )`

```
<?php 

    include 'mailer.php';

    if(isset($_GET['success'])){

        if($_GET['success'] == 1 )  
        {

          echo "<div class=\"form-messages success\"> Thank you! Your message has been sent. </div>";

        }
        elseif($_GET['success'] == -1 )  
        {

          echo "<div class=\"form-messages error\"> Oops! Something went wrong please try again. </div>";

        }

    }
?>
```